# Create a notification between methods in the same class

Tags: java, timer

sorry to disturb you but it's been 2 days on th same problem and i don't find the solution so i come for your help .
I think the solution is very simple but i can't find it .

Here it is, i am actually using a timer ( the one Java provides) and i want that at the end of my timer , one small notification or something like that tell it to my other method .

So here is my code :

```
internTimer = new Timer(true);

public void changeRound() {
    stopTimer();
    launchTimer();
    changeLayer();

}

public void changeLayer() {
    this.view.getRadarImage().removeLayer(this.view.getControlTowerLayer());
    this.view.setControlTowerLayer();

}


public void launchTimer() {
        internTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("run");
            }
        }, (long) 10000);

}

public void stopTimer() {
    System.out.println("stopTimer");
    internTimer.cancel();
}
```

So as you can see all i need to do (as i think ) is just call something in my run method but i don't know what .

So i would like to call either method changeLayer() or changeRound() . but i can't cause i don't have access to my view in my thread.

So as you can see i'm very confused and if you could help me i would be very greatfull.

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally i solved my problem, i jsu thad to use Plateform.runLater configuration !
If it can help someone , that's it !